# Wait for the database server in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, database, asp.net-core

My ASP.NET Core web application uses a database for almost everything it does. Without the database available it cannot generate a single page. So it's important that the database is available when the application starts. (I'm worrying about intermitting database outages later, beginning with the startup for now.) Since the database runs on a separate host, it may well be down while the web app should be started.

Also, I'm ensuring that the correct database schema is installed when the app starts. If the database schema is not up-to-date, it may be incompatible with the installed application version and crashes or data corruption may occur. So the first thing my app does is looking at the database schema and upgrading it if needed.

I'm now looking for ways to handle the database down situation and let the app wait for the database.

- If I do nothing, the app just crashes at startup and systemd may restart it for a short while before giving up, leaving the app unavailable forever.
- If I check the database once at startup only, this will fail. I then catch the exception and shortcut the application pipeline with a simple error message result. The app will be unavailable with a simple message until restarted. This it my current situation.

Are there any best practices to wait for a database connection at startup? I'd imagine I just probe the connection and wait for it to succeed. This must block the `Configure` method because so much other initialisation work has to be done there but cannot be done without the database. But if the web app should be shut down before it could see the database, it must also be possible to cancel the wait and gracefully shutdown the app.

Here's the current simplified code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(…)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            // ...
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}

class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
            .AddDbContext<MainDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MainDbContext")));
        // Other services
        services.AddMvc(…);
    }

    public void Configure(
    {
        // ...

        // Set up database
        try
        {
            // Check and upgrade database schema...

            // TODO: Block until database is ready; allow cancellation
        }
        catch
        {
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("The application could not be " +
                    "initialized correctly. See the service log for details.");
            });
            return;
        }

        // Initialise other services using database data...

        // Set up ASP.NET
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(…);
    }
}
```

Comment: curious to see suggestions. i'm essentially doing the same thing, but don't see any other way around it.

Comment: What we ended up doing was exposing an action method in our application that checks all the required dependencies - such as databases, file systems and external APIs. If theyre all available, the action method returns a 200 response. If not, it logs the dependencies that failed and returns a 500 error. Then we set our load balancer's health check tool to hit this action method once every 30 seconds. If it fails, it marks that server as down and won't direct traffic to it. If all servers are down, then it returns a friendly maintenance page saying that we're working on bringing the site back up

Comment: You might also read [Scott Hanselman's blog entry](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetUpASPNETCore22HealthChecksWithBeatPulsesAspNetCoreDiagnosticsHealthChecks.aspx) on health checks. I didn't use that myself (our main app is still .NET Framework and old ASP.NET) but it's some good info.

Comment: I've got an app_offline.htm page (inspired by the IIS integration, but ported to Apache/Linux) so that part is covered. No load balancer here (yet). But I don't want to serve that and leave the user alone. I want the app to work properly as soon as the database is there. (And maybe even serve a "temporary error" page until then if possible.)

Comment: My 2 cents: 

Start signalr in a background service

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Redirect to a "landing page" in case of db failure and feed data about availability of db via signalr to the connected clients.
When the db is available again show a link/redirect using javascript to desired page.

Comment: with sqlServer there is an option:  .UseSqlServer(connection, options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()) idk if its also available for you